# Time until a TCP socket closes if the connection is lost

Tags: tcp

How long will a TCP socket remain open if there's a loss of a network connection between the source and the destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loss of network connection between client and server will only be detected if packets are transmitted and the response (ACK) is missing. Packets will only be transmitted if data are sent or if TCP keep alive is used (i.e "empty" data). Thus if neither TCP keep alive is used nor data are transmitted the socket will be considered open forever. If TCP keep alive is used the detection time depends on the settings of the keep alive timer.